# "does not support writing" IOException when opening Access 97 .mdb file with Jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I need to open an `.mdb` file to recover some genealogy data.

I try Jackacess 2.1.5 but I get the following `java.io.IOException`:

> file format [V1997 [VERSION_3]] does not support writing for Genealogy.mdb

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that exception with an Access_97 database file if you try to do

```java
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(dbPath));
```

but you can avoid the exception if you do this instead

```java
Database db = new DatabaseBuilder()
        .setFile(new File(dbPath))
        .setReadOnly(true)
        .open();
```

**Update:** This should no longer be an issue. Using the static `.open(file)` method, Jackcess 2.1.6 and later will simply open the Access 97 database file as read-only instead of throwing an exception.